# Why Google Analytics does not count visits when browser does not load images

Tags: google-analytics, visitors

I tested many times using Firefox and Chrome.
When I disable loading images in browsers, Google analytics doesn't count visit.
Why?

Comment: Can you share an URL to see what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics by default, uses image as the transport mechanism for sending hit data. So, for someone that has images disabled via the browser, then the information doesnt get sent.
You can change the behaviour to use beacon as the transport method instead
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data#specify_different_transport_mechanisms